# How to enable tracing in a c# interop assembly

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, com-interop

I would like to trace `HTTP` communication in my `c#` assembly (`.Net 4.5`). As the .Net code is wrapped with COM interop and finally used in COM container applications I have no `app.config` file of the main app to configure tracing the usual way.

What I have found so far was always at some point tied to `app.config` (e.g. rewrite that file and load with `ConfigurationMagager` or `Trace.refresh()`)

There is an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049442/system-net-httpwebrequest-tracing-without-using-files-or-app-config) about enabling tracing at runtime without an `app.config` file using *reflection*. Is this the only route or is there a simpler way to switch on tracing, say, for the *DEBUG* version of such an assembly?

Comment: You always can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.

Comment: There certainly *is* an app.config file, it must be stored in the same directory as the client EXE and have a matching name.  That the client programmer did not use .NET is not relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant: you are absolutely right. I was locked into my stream of thought that I did not even check. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jdweng: Besides Hans' advice I will use fiddler to log additional information.